# jquery selector for multiple div Vticker

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have two division with class named "tick" what i am trying to do here is if the content overflows then only the ticker should be activated.

```
div1 : <div class="home tick">
div2 : <div class="rbar tick">
```

**problem:** if content overflows in one div the other div also starts ticking any solution ?

```
if( ($('.tick > ul').height()) > 160){
    $('.tick').vTicker({ 
        speed: 500,
        pause: 3000,
        animation: 'fade',
        showItems: 3,
        height: 192
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take each div separately:

```
$('.tick > ul').each(function(){
  if( ($(this).height()) > 160){
    $(this).parent().vTicker({ 
        speed: 500,
        pause: 3000,
        animation: 'fade',
        showItems: 3,
        height: 192
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved the day 4 me :)